# Title being appended to featured image link

Tags: wordpress

For some reason the titles of my featured images are being appended to their links. I can't figure out why it's happening.. any ideas?

"Test image" is the text that appears next to the image.

```
<a href="http://localhost/mysite/test/" class="post-thumbnail" aria-hidden="true">
<img src="http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/ds/2017/12/sample2-1080xauto-c-default.jpg" class="featured-image tease-featured-image " alt="<span itemprop=" name"="">Test Image" /&gt;
</a>
```

And it's the post title, not the image title that's displaying. Removing the image title doesn't do anything. Changing the title of the post changes the text.

Comment: I think the HTML is generated is malformed. Did you posted the generated html correctly? Did you made any code changes, if any post the same. It will help us to understand and debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you have a span inside your alt?

The alt is for people who can't see images -

Normally the rules for alts is :

- No special characters. This includes UTF-8 characters such as unencoded curly quotes, as well as HTML Character Entities.
- No HTML.
- No more than 125 characters.
- Just identify the picture. No need to refer to it (“This is a picture
  of…”).

Read more at: https://html.com/attributes/img-alt/

Also - the span created is not closed properly.